# Angular2 Routers are not detecting Dynamic Content

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am having Problem in Angular2 Routers. The Problem is Routers are not detecting Dynamic Content in my components.

There is a home page which consist of only static content, after that I have a Products page in which i am using ngFor directive to dynamically showing all products which are stored as an object in a service. When i click on Products in navbar, ngFor directive did not work, it only shows static content in the page(heading etc)

When i double click on Products page in nav bar it works.

**Bootstrap.ts:**

```js
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser"
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component"
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';


bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

**Root Component:**

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, RouterOutlet, RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

import {Home} from './home.component';
import {Products} from './products.component';
import {SubmitPost} from './submitPost.component';
import {MyAccount} from './myaccount.component';
import {ProductList} from './productList.service';
import {AccountData} from './accountdata.service'
import {LoginVerification} from './loginverification.service'


@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: Home, useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/products', name: 'Products', component: Products},
  {path: '/submitad', name: 'SubmitAd', component: SubmitPost},
  {path: '/myaccount', name: 'MyAccount', component: MyAccount},
  {path: '/*other', name: 'Other', redirectTo: ['Home']}

])

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css'],
  directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
  providers: [ProductList, AccountData, LoginVerification]
})


export class AppComponent{
}
```

**Products Component:**

```js
                    <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor = "#product of allProducts">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body" >
                                <img [src]="product.imageUrl" alt="">                            
                                <h3><a (click)="showPost(product)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{product.title}}</a></h3>
                                <p>Price: {{product.price}} Rs.</p>
                                <p>City: {{product.city}}, {{product.state}}</p>
                                <p>Category: {{product.category}}</p>
                                <p>Cell: {{product.cell}}</p>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```
        <nav class="nav navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SHOP19</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">                        
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navOpt">
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['Products']">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['SubmitAd']">Submit An Ad</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['MyAccount']">My Account</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 


                </ul>

                <div class="pull-right" id="search">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>            

            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Please don't use snippets feature when the code is not actually runnable inline. I see only blue buttons in your question ;-)

Comment: I don't understand what the question is about. This seems to be about the router. I don't see `routerLink`s or `<router-outlet>`s.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer OP is also not using `Angular 2` final release

Comment: Right, old Angular2 version. Which one?

Comment: I am unable to figure out to version, but its not the final version

Comment: i have added router-outlet and router-Link

Comment: What component is it that contains the routerlinks and the router-outlet? The root component?